# Link preview in Telegram client expose IP address?

Tags: security, ip-address, links, preview, telegram-messenger

When you receive a link in telegram messenger there is a small preview of what you see when opening the link. Will this preview expose the clients IP address already or is that preview generated in any way on the telegram servers so the client doesn't make a HTTP request to see the preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't expose your IP address.

You can check that the link previews are generated by logging in through https://web.telegram.org with any modern browser and inspecting the code - <kbd>F12</kbd> -> <kbd>Inspect element icon</kbd> in Chrome, for instance.

This is an example that gets output:

```
<img class="media-photo" src="blob:https://web.telegram.org/6d836345-be5b-4c01-9f70-92d2b59cb42c">
```

As you can see, the link leads to Telegram domain and is also a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).